# How to execute JPA Entity manager operations inside Quarkus-Kafka consumer method

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus

Dears, I want to update my domain entities according to message being received by Kafka topic. I am using Quarkus latest and Smallrye reactive messaging with Kafka. Pub-sub model is working fine with me, but in consumer method I am unable to update my entities using entityManager or HibernatePanache.

Whenever I try to use entityManager code inside consumer message, an exception is being thrown and handled silently. Here is my consumer code :

```java
@Transactional
@Incoming("new-payment")
public CompletionStage<Void> updateTotalBuyers(String paymentEvent) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            PaymentEvent event = jsonb.fromJson(paymentEvent, PaymentEvent.class);
            TypedQuery<Book> query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b where b.isbn=:isbn", Book.class);
            query.setParameter("isbn", event.getIsbn());
            Book book = query.getSingleResult();
            book.setTotalBuyers(book.getTotalBuyers() + 1);
            em.merge(book);
        });
    }
```

If anyone has a working code snippet for my problem it would be great. Also, how can I print that silent exception for further debugging ?

**Update :**
I surrounded the code with try/catch block and the below exception is being thrown :

> javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: interface javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.zig:83)
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.getOrCreateEntityManager(RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.zig:191)
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager.getEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:78)
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createQuery(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:317)
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.ForwardingEntityManager.createQuery(ForwardingEntityManager.java:142)
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.find(JpaOperations.java:208)
>       at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.find(JpaOperations.java:200)
>       at org.ibra.ebs.book.model.Book.find(Book.java)
>       at org.ibra.ebs.book.service.BookService.lambda$updateTotalBuyers$0(BookService.java:106)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1618)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

I added annotation `@ActivateRequestContext` on both class and method with no luck.

Update : I tried to elevate context-propagation using

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-streams-operators</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also same exception is being thrown with some context-propagation classes (which means it is being activated).

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried changing the debugging level?

Comment: I am already enabling ALL logs : quarkus.log.console.level=ALL

Comment: As a conclusion of this I've 2 alternative to make this work and both of these solutions need to get rid of JPA from your application:
1-Either use on of Quarkus reactive sql clients (Which is not supporting all RDBMS yet).

2-Use Vert.x JDBC client to access database.

Comment: Not sure how you solved it, but I'd assumed the Quarkus Context Propagation Module would handle these scenarios: https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PepperBob, I was just trying that too :) and I tried adding these dependencies and it didn't work with me : 
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-streams-operators</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-rxjava2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
Do I need to do something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it worked :), Yes the answer was around context-propagation and here is what I did :

```
@Transactional
@Incoming("new-payment")
public CompletionStage<?> updateTotalBuyers(Message<String> paymentEvent) {

    //TODO: move to CDI producer
    ManagedExecutor executor = ManagedExecutor.builder()
            .maxAsync(5)
            .propagated(ThreadContext.CDI, 
                        ThreadContext.TRANSACTION)
            .build();
    //TODO: move to CDI producer
    ThreadContext threadContext = ThreadContext.builder()
                     .propagated(ThreadContext.CDI, 
                                 ThreadContext.TRANSACTION)
                     .build();

    return executor.runAsync(threadContext.contextualRunnable(() -> {
        try {
            log.info("Into update total buyers");
            PaymentEvent event = jsonb.fromJson(paymentEvent.getPayload(), PaymentEvent.class);
            Book book = Book.find("isbn", event.getIsbn()).singleResult();
            book.totalBuyers++;
            book.persist();
            log.info("Total books {}", book.totalBuyers);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Something wrong happened !!!", e);
        } finally {
            paymentEvent.ack();
        }
    }));
}
```

I will try to make it more standard now.

Answer (score 4):

I had simillar issue using Quarkus + a single thread executor to collect AWS SQS messages.

- Initial - **wrong** approach:

```
private final ExecutorService scheduler  = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
scheduler.submit(/*MyRunnable*/)
```

- **Solution**: Injecting *ManagedExecutor* which is provided by quarkus:

```
@Inject
ManagedExecutor managedExecutor;
managedExecutor.submit(/*MyRunnable*/);
```

In your particular case you can **replace following code** with injecting **ManagedExecutor**.

```
ManagedExecutor executor = ManagedExecutor.builder()
        .maxAsync(5)
        .propagated(ThreadContext.CDI, 
                    ThreadContext.TRANSACTION)
        .build();
//TODO: move to CDI producer
ThreadContext threadContext = ThreadContext.builder()
                 .propagated(ThreadContext.CDI, 
                             ThreadContext.TRANSACTION)
                 .build();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, but it doesn't work for me, the system stale when I try to persist my entity:
@Incoming("placeEnricher")
    @Transactional
    fun search(placeEnrichEvent: PlaceEnrichEvent): Future<*> {
        return managedExecutor.supplyAsync {
            println("saving...")
            val place = Place(...)
            println("constructed...")
            em.persist(place)
            println("saved...")
        }
}

What I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add `@ApplicationScoped` and  `@ActivateRequestContext` both these annotations on the class and `@Transactional` annotation on the `updateTotalBuyers` method.

Cheers!

Comment: I've tried this approach before and I mentioned this in my question.

Comment: This solution is simpler and it has worked for me in calls to methods with a Proxi object.