# quarkus-vertx: non-blocking db call from verticle results in ContextNotActiveException

Tags: asynchronous, spring-data-jpa, vert.x, quarkus

i send a message via Vert.x EventBus. The listening verticle starts a non blocking call to backend to read all entities from DB. My problem is an exception during the call to the DB: ContextNotActiveException. I tried panache and spring-data and get the same result in both cases (probably same mistake in both of them!?).

```
@Path("/vertx")
@Log
public class ApiVertx extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Inject
    EventBus eventBus;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void getViaSpringData() {
        System.out.println("\n-send to bus: START");
        eventBus.request(ConsumerAsyncSpringData.CONSUMER_ADR_SPRING_DATA, "", event -> {
            System.out.println("\tRespons is ready.");
            if (event.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("\tSuccess: " + event.result()
                        .body());
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tSuccess: NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        });
        System.out.println("+send to bus: OK");
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConsumerAsyncPanache extends AbstractVerticle {
    public static final String CONSUMER_ADR_PANACHE = "CONSUMER_ADR_PANACHE";

    @ConsumeEvent(ConsumerAsyncPanache.CONSUMER_ADR_PANACHE)
//    @ActivateRequestContext
    @Transactional
    public CompletionStage<String> getAllPets(String str) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-------------------------- ConsumerAsyncPanache started");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                List<Pet> petLst = Pet.listAll(Sort.by("name"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("############################### " + e.toString());
                throw e;
            }
            return "testString";
        }, executorService);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Pet extends PanacheEntity {
    @Column(length = 40, unique = true)
    public String name;
}
```

curl localhost:8080/vertx produces following

```
-send to bus: START
+send to bus: OK
-------------------------- ConsumerAsyncPanache started
############################### javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: interface 
javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
        Respons is ready.
        Success: NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

An approach with spring data. With the same result.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConsumerAsyncSpringData extends AbstractVerticle {
    public static final String CONSUMER_ADR_SPRING_DATA = "CONSUMER_ADR_SPRING_DATA";

    @Inject
    private FruitRepository fruitRepository;

    @ConsumeEvent(ConsumerAsyncSpringData.CONSUMER_ADR_SPRING_DATA)
    public CompletionStage<String> getAllPets(String str) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("-------------------------- consumer started");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                fruitRepository.findAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("############################### " + e.toString());
                throw e;
            }
            return "Spring-Data";
        }, executorService);
    }
}
```

```
public interface FruitRepository extends CrudRepository<Fruit, Long> {}
```

Corresponding output

```
-send to bus: START
+send to bus: OK
-------------------------- ConsumerAsyncSpringData started
############################### javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: 
interface javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
        Respons is ready.
        Success: NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through similar problem and solved with `smallrye-context-propagation`
extension. Please check this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534957/how-to-execute-jpa-entity-manager-operations-inside-quarkus-kafka-consumer-metho?noredirect=1#comment105748663_58534957) that explains how it is being solved.